# Error 'Didn't find class on path: DexPathList'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

after importing a bunch (2) of libraries with Gradle, I get the following errors in the Logcat:

https://gist.github.com/devyanlab/1b18fbe67309f3a07d5d

I think the main error that caused the emulator to crash is:

Didn't find class "de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.devyanlab.qomento-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.devyanlab.qomento-1, /system/lib]]

I've been searching all week and tried all the possible solutions, but none of them worked.

Any toughts?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to add de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView to your project as a dependency?

In Android Studio:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}
```

In Eclipse:
Download the [CircleImageView project from GitHub](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) and add it to your project as a library.

Hope it helps :)